# How to merge three tab limited column into a single column

Tags: comm

I have two text files:

**file1**

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6
```

**file2**

```
1  
a  
2  
b  
c  
3
```

Expected output is a file combining the two files, provided the rows present in two files are written only once:

```
1  
2  
3   
4  
5  
6  
a  
b  
c
```

I tried `comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`
It gives three separate columns. But I need all three separate columns as one single column.

Answer (score 0):

Try `uniq` or `sort -u`.

```
cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq
```

or

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u
```

should both give the desired results. Or use `tr` do delete the unwanted tabs:

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | tr -d '[[:blank:]]'
```